# C# insert query execution

Tags: c#, .net

I have inserted a row in database in run-time, if execution is successful it should display positive message if not executed, it should display negative message.I have only done the positive scenario, I like to get the negative message as well. please help me out guys

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into Master Values('" + textBox1.Text + "'," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text + ",'" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "');");
            sc.Connection = con;
            int o;
o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("saved");
```

Comment: Consider rephrasing your SQL as a parameterized query so you're not setting yourself up for SQL injection.  How do you propose detecting that the query failed?

Comment: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things you'd be looking to check to determine the "success" of the query.  Specifically:

1. Exceptions
2. Affected rows

The first is taken care of by exception handling.  For example:

```
try
{
    ...
    o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("saved");
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    // there was an error from the database, handle it here
}
```

The second can be examined by the return value stored in `o`.  (Which, by the way, is a *very* unintuitive variable name.)  Something like:

```
if (o < 1)
{
    // no rows were updated, handle that condition here
}
```

Or, conversely, depending on your business logic:

```
if (o > 1)
{
    // *multiple* rows were updated, is that what you wanted?
}
```

Side Note: Please be aware that your code is *wide open* to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You'll want to use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx) to help guard against this.

Comment: o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); if this code is sucessfully executed, A value will get stored in o. then we can make a message that the data is saved. if the query is wrong, the execution of above statement will show error and no values will get stored in o, then how can we display saying that the execution is unsuccessful.

Comment: @user3840562: What you show to the user or how you show it is up to you.  The conditions you're looking for, however, are either exceptions or an unexpected value in the result.

Comment: Can we check if loop for sc.ExecuteNonQuery() ???

Comment: @user3840562: I'm afraid that comment makes no sense...

Comment: thank you....sir....Exception method....worked